# php parrent::__construct and oop

Tags: php, oop, parent, construct

hey I am fairly new to oop and while learning i got to a problem that tortures me more than 2 hours.

could you please tell me why `this-> flavor` do not get `"grape"` value?

```
<?php
class Product{
    public $name = "default-name";
    public $price = 50;
    public $desc = "default_description";

    function __construct ($jemali, $zviadi, $chuuch){
        $this->name=$jemali;
        $this->price=$zviadi;
        $this->desc=$chuuch;
    }

    public function getInfo(){
        return "product name:".$this->name;
    }
}

class Soda extends Product {
    public $flavor="default flavor";

    function __consturct($jemali, $zviadi, $chuuch, $lavor){

        parent::__construct($jemali, $zviadi, $chuuch);
        $this->flavor=$lavor;
    }

    public function getInfo(){
        return "product name:".$this->name." flavor ".$this->flavor;
    }
}

//$shirt = new Product("miriani", 10, "magari");
$soda = new Soda("jemala", 12, "chuchuka", "grape");
//echo $shirt->getInfo();
echo "<br />";
echo $soda->getInfo();
?>
```

the output is product name:jemala flavor default flavor

Comment: Check your spelling. `__consturct` is not the same as `__construct`.

Answer (score 1):

Just a small mistake - Wrong spelling of `__construct`. Use the code below

```
<?php
class Product{
    public $name = "default-name";
    public $price = 50;
    public $desc = "default_description";

    function __construct ($jemali, $zviadi, $chuuch){
        $this->name=$jemali;
        $this->price=$zviadi;
        $this->desc=$chuuch;
    }

    public function getInfo(){
        return "product name:".$this->name;
    }
}

class Soda extends Product {
    public $flavor="default flavor";

    function __construct($jemali, $zviadi, $chuuch, $lavor){

        parent::__construct($jemali, $zviadi, $chuuch);
        $this->flavor=$lavor;
    }

    public function getInfo(){
        return "product name:".$this->name." flavor ".$this->flavor;
    }
}

//$shirt = new Product("miriani", 10, "magari");
$soda = new Soda("jemala", 12, "chuchuka", "grape");
//echo $shirt->getInfo();
echo "<br />";
echo $soda->getInfo();
?>
```

Hope this helps you